# activeadmin - override strong params for comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin

I am trying to add an attribute called `category` to an active admin comment.  I have successfully changed the comment form.  When I submit the comment, I get the following:

```
Started POST "/admin/comments" for ::1 at 2017-05-27 08:20:41 -0400
Processing by Admin::CommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"vaGGzKnE10Nn/QmIzBk+2K0OqvheX6hPRHlm9F9BJkEL1I6D9YDz+qx1d1ekuuVkIfnqYamXqc5aLJH3TFdF4g==", "active_admin_comment"=>{"resource_type"=>"Person", "resource_id"=>"1203", "body"=>"test comment with category", "category"=>"Adventures"}, "commit"=>"Add Comment"}
  AdminUser Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "admin_users".* FROM "admin_users" WHERE "admin_users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "admin_users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: category
```

As you can see, I can't save the category.  I can't figure out how to access the strong params of an active admin comment.  How do I do that?

Comment: My question is about how to access the controller code when using the activeadmin gem.  It does the controller stuff behind the scenes - i need to figure out how to access it.

Comment: Ohh, have you read [this](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/2-resource-customization.md)? You can set your own attributes in strong params.

Comment: Thanks, but thats for an active admin resource.  This is not a resource - comments come included in activeadmin and their code is hidden somewhere in the gem

Answer (score 0):

The comment permit_parameters are registered [in this DSL](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/orm/active_record/comments.rb#L77). The DSL dynamically defines a permitted_params method in the resource comments controller [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource_dsl.rb#L69).  Perhaps it is possible to use [after_load](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin.rb#L114) to update the permitted parameters.